# automake: exclude intermediary source file from "dist" tarballs

Tags: autotools, automake

I have a intermediary source file `foobar.c` which is automatically generated from `foobar.c.in` via a sed script.  The `dist` target created via autotools includes `foobar.c` in the generated tarballs.  What do I do in `Makefile.am` or in `configure.ac` to exclude `foobar.c`?

Comment: I don't think there can be a good answer without more context - can you show the Automake rule that generates foobar.c?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is actually quite simple

```
nodist_foobar_SOURCES = foobar.c
BUILT_SOURCES = foobar.c
```

This way automake knows that `foobar.c` is generated at build time, and since it's in `nodist_` it won't be redistributed.

Although depending on what kind of string you're talking about a common way to solve it is to use a preprocessor macro and have it passed as `CPPFLAGS`

```
foobar_CPPFLAGS = "-DSOMESTRING=\"$(somevariable)\""
```

and then just use `SOMESTRING` in the code and let the preprocessor handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by changing from using a sed script to modify `foobar.c.in` to having `configure` determine the needed strings and stick them into `config.h`, which is included by a non-intermediary version of `foobar.c`.  `config.h` isn't included in the tarballs.

However, it still seems like there should be some method to tell autotools to exclude certain files from the dist tarballs.